# UIImage to NSData Return Null

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, base64, nsdata

I want to put several .png images into a database backed by mongodb:

```
// Image data array
NSMutableArray *allImgData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (UIButton *photoButton in self.photoButtons) {
    UIImage *buttonImage = [photoButton imageForState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(buttonImage);
    // add to image data array for upload
    [allImgData addObject:imgData];
}
```

Then I append the image data to http body data:

```
// Append image data to body
NSMutableData *bodyData = [NSMutableData data];
int i = 1;
for (NSData *imgData in allImgData) {
    [bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"%@%d.png\"\r\n", fileParamConstant, i] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [bodyData appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [bodyData appendData:imgData];
    [bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    i++;
}
// Append one last boundary
[bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:bodyData];
```

When I try to convert the image data saved in the database back to UIImage, it is always Null:

```
        if (photo1 && photo1.count != 0) {
                    NSData *data = [photo1[0] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                    NSLog(@"Data is here: %@", data);
                    // Data is here: <efbfbd50 4e470d0a 1a0a0000 000d4948 0000efbf bd000000 28000000 efbfbd00 0000efbf ...

                    UIImage *photo1Image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                    NSLog(@"Image is here: %@", photo1Image);
                    // Image is here: (null)

                    [self.photo1Button setImage:photo1Image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }
```

I think the data looks correct, but why the image is not interpreted in a right way?

**Update**

Objective C Part:

```
- (void) uploadPhotoData {
// NSURLSession Submit/Resubmit data
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
// NSURL
NSString *userName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"LoginUserName"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://localhost:8080/api/users/competitorProductPhotoData/%@", userName]];
NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
// "Put" method
// Request setup
// [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest addValue:@"image/png" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
//    [urlRequest setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
//    [urlRequest setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
//    [urlRequest setTimeoutInterval:3000];
// Set boundary and content type (boundary is a random String)
NSString *boundaryConstant = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"---------------------------14737809831464368775746641449"];
NSString* fileParamConstant = @"photo";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundaryConstant];
[urlRequest setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
// Image data array
NSMutableArray *allImgData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (UIButton *photoButton in self.photoButtons) {
    UIImage *buttonImage = [photoButton imageForState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(buttonImage);
    // NSString *imgString = [UIImagePNGRepresentation(buttonImage) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
    // add to image data array for upload
    [allImgData addObject:imgData];
}
// Append image data to body data
NSMutableData *bodyData = [NSMutableData data];
int i = 1;
for (NSData *imgData in allImgData) {
    [bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"%@%d.png\"\r\n", fileParamConstant, i] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [bodyData appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [bodyData appendData:imgData];
    [bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    i++;
}
// Append one last boundary
[bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:bodyData];
// set the content-length
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[bodyData length]];
[urlRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
// Start session task
NSURLSessionUploadTask* task = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:urlRequest fromData:bodyData completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil && [(NSHTTPURLResponse*)response statusCode] < 300) {
        if (error == nil) {
            NSLog(@"Successfully submitted photo data. No error.");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Photo data Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                self.submitImageButton.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"WrongUser"];
            }];
        }
    }
}];
[task resume];
```

}

Node.js Part:

```
// on routes that end in /users/competitorProductPhotoData
// ----------------------------------------------------
router.route('/users/competitorProductPhotoData/:userName')

// update the user info (accessed at PUT     http://localhost:8080/api/users/competitorAnalysisPhotoData)
.post(function(req, res) {

    // Parse Multipart-data form upload
    var form = new multiparty.Form();

    // Errors may be emitted
    // Note that if you are listening to 'part' events, the same error may be
    // emitted from the `form` and the `part`.
    form.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('Error parsing form: ' + err.stack);
    });

    form.on('file', function(err, files) {
        fs.readFile(files.path, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error reading file path: ' + err.stack);
            }

            // Upload photo to the embedded document
            if (files.originalFilename === 'photo1.png') {
                User.findOneAndUpdate(
                    { userName : req.params.userName},
                    { $set:
                        { "competitorProductPhoto.0.photo1" : data }
                    },
                    { upsert : true },
                    function(err, user) {
                        // After mongodb is done updating, you are receiving the updated file as callback

                        // Now you can send the error or updated file to client
                        if (err)
                            return res.send(err);
                        return;
                    });
            } else if (files.originalFilename === 'photo2.png') {
                User.findOneAndUpdate(
                    { userName : req.params.userName},
                    { $set:
                        { "competitorProductPhoto.0.photo2" : data }
                    },
                    { upsert : true },
                    function(err, user) {
                        // After mongodb is done updating, you are receiving the updated file as callback

                        // Now you can send the error or updated file to client
                        if (err)
                            return res.send(err);
                        return;
                    });
            } else if (files.originalFilename === 'photo3.png') {
                User.findOneAndUpdate(
                    { userName : req.params.userName},
                    { $set:
                        { "competitorProductPhoto.0.photo3" : data }
                    },
                    { upsert : true },
                    function(err, user) {
                        // After mongodb is done updating, you are receiving the updated file as callback

                        // Now you can send the error or updated file to client
                        if (err)
                            return res.send(err);
                        return;
                    });
            } else if (files.originalFilename === 'photo4.png') {
                User.findOneAndUpdate(
                    { userName : req.params.userName},
                    { $set:
                        { "competitorProductPhoto.0.photo4" : data }
                    },
                    { upsert : true },
                    function(err, user) {
                        // After mongodb is done updating, you are receiving the updated file as callback

                        // Now you can send the error or updated file to client
                        if (err)
                            return res.send(err);
                        return;
                    });
            }
        });
    });

    // form.parse(req);
    form.parse(req);
})
```

Schema:

```
// create competitorProductPhotoSchema
var CompetitorProductPhoto = new Schema({
    photo1: {type: String},
    photo2: {type: String},
    photo3: {type: String},
    photo4: {type: String}
});
```

Comment: If `photo1[0]` is an `NSString` then why do you think its UTF-8 encoded data is an image? It can't be. Is the string a base64 representation of the image data?

Comment: @rmaddy I use "[bodyData appendData:imgData];". It seems like it does not specify whether it is UTF-8 or base64?

Comment: Regardless, the UTF-8 encoding of an `NSString` can't ever be valid image data. There's at least one step missing in there. Update your question with a log of `photo1[0]` (the actual string). If it looks like base64 data then you need to convert the `NSString` to `NSData` by decoding the base64 string, not getting its UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: @rmaddy When I try to log photo1[0] as a NSString directly, it shows a question mark with "PNG": "?PNG". I have actually tried to decode with base64 before UTF-8, and it is also null.

Comment: Update your question showing how you actually populate the `photo1` array.

Comment: @rmaddy It is all updated. I think the reason why photo1 is an array is because of mongodb's schema. Actually I only populate one photo1 but I need to use photo1[0] to access it.